# Prime ideals in group ring

Tags: group-rings

Let $R$ be a ring of characteristic $p$ (can assume $R=\mathbb{F}_q$ if it makes things significantly easier) and $G$ be a finite group. Do we know anything about the prime ideals in $R[G]$? I've tried multiple searches including terms like "prime ideals","group algebras","group algebras" but I've found very little information.

Thanks